# Simplifying Regular Expression Quantifiers

Tags: regex

I'm currently working on a library that simplifies creating regular expression patterns.

To generate the most legible patterns, I'd like to simplify quantifiers where possible. Assume the following subpattern has been emitted:

```
(?:\d+)?
```

The above can be simplified to `\d*`, but is it also correct to assume that `(?:ℝ+)?` can always be simplified to `ℝ*`, where `ℝ` is an arbitrary (parenthesized, if necessary) regular expression?

If yes, the same should hold true for the following, right?

- `(?:ℝ+)?` => `ℝ*`
- `(?:ℝ+)*` => `ℝ*`
- `(?:ℝ+)+` => `ℝ+`
- `(?:ℝ*)?` => `ℝ*`
- `(?:ℝ*)*` => `ℝ*`
- `(?:ℝ*)+` => `ℝ*`
- `(?:ℝ?)?` => `ℝ?`
- `(?:ℝ?)+` => `ℝ*`
- `(?:ℝ?)*` => `ℝ*`

Comment: Should be true for all of them, assuming that nothing happens that makes them non-greedy (and I don't think it will).

Comment: Apart from all the great suggestions, you can also cheat a little and peek at regex-opt (c++), Regexp:Assemble and Regexp:Assemble::Compress (perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. And you should always use the smaller one, as the nested repetitions are prone to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). So apart from different execution behavior, they will match the same languages.

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking is precisely what I'm trying to avoid here, therefore the effort. How about lazy quantifiers, though? If the inner quantifier is lazy, so should the result be, if I'm correct, but what about the outer one?

Comment: I'd rather expect `lazyness = max(inner, outer)`. Both need to be non-greedy to be reduced to a single non-greedy operator.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest converting the quantifiers into (*m*, *n*) repetition counts:

- `*` is (0, ∞),
- `+` is (1, ∞), and
- `?` is (0, 1).

Then work out the rules for combining quantifiers. In general, what is `(ℝ{m1, n1}){m2, n2}`? Off the top of my head, I'd guess you could simplify that to `ℝ{m1·m2, n1·n2}` if neither *m*<sub>1</sub> nor *m*<sub>2</sub> is greater than 1.